# Parametric equations in rectangular form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$y=t^2+4, x=2t-5$

Graph and state any restrictions on the domain.

I need to state any restrictions on the domain but don't know how.

I added 5 to both sides of the x equation and then I divided by the 2.

Then I took the x equation and plugged it into the y equation.

Here is what I have at this point:

$y=\dfrac{x^2+10x+25}{4}+\dfrac{16}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from graph there are no restrictions on the x- domain, since

$ −∞<t<+∞ ,\, −∞<x<+∞ .  $

Comment: Did you mean to write $-\infty < t \color{red}{<} +\infty$, $-\infty < x \color{red}{<} +\infty$?

Comment: Thanks, shall correct typo.